# How can I make the development server in Python Django be on the internet?

Tags: python, django

I want to make the development server in Django be on the internet while running Windows 10. How can I do this?

By the way, when I try to use my external IP, it doesn't work. It says that I can't use it

Comment: Assuming your have a public ip, it's as easy as pointing to your http://<your public ip>:<django dev server port> from a browser... What is really your question?

Comment: @mguijarr My question is that I'm trying to access my development server anywhere in the world

Comment: Are you adamant in running the server from your own PC or is your end goal to simply have it accessible over the internet instead of locally?

Comment: It is highly discouraged to use the development server in a public-facing configuration. The development server has not been tested for security, and is highly inefficient.

Comment: @knbk I would just need to see how good my site looks like when it is live.

Comment: @ErionV I'm want to run it so that I can access the website anywhere.

Comment: Then you can use any number of options to run your site in a production-like environment, ranging from Heroku and the like, to a production-level webserver on your machine, or a VPS.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend running it on an external server and not giving access to your local server to the rest of the world. Especially if running in debug. You could deploy it to a free dyno on Heroku. Try going through this simple tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python) and you should be able to access your Django project anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion, this is an old question but what actually happened was that I didn't add any port forwarding rules on my router. If I did, then the solutions raised by others would've worked. Since I didn't port forward, I just ended up hosting it on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

While starting the Django Server, mention the IP and PORT from which you want to accept the requests. Mention `0.0.0.0` to open it for all as:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

By default the Django's server accepts requests only via `localhost`.

Now make a request via using public IP of the system on which your Django's server is running

Comment: Its not working. When I do the command, it works but if I try my public IP along with the port in my browser, it doesn't work. Could it be a firewall issue?

Comment: Yes, it can be due to firewall. Default HTTP port on browser is 80, I guess you must be already knowing that

Comment: The port I set it to be is 8000

Comment: and you are making request with port like `your.public.ip.address:8000` in browser?

Comment: Yes. I have been doing it that way

Comment: Also make sure that in your `ALLOWED_HOST` configuration in `setting.py` is set as `['*']` in order to allow connection from all

Answer (score 1):

You can try a deployment on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python). Is relativelly easy to set up and provides you with a live server in minutes.

Comment: I have added the link to the specific python documentation above. You need an account. The you need to follow the documentation. A great tutorial from django-girls here: https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/heroku/